# Load Image With Coil Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Why I can't load the image with URL, already use coil dependency

```
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:0.11.0"
```

and then add internet permission in manifest like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but when I do something like this, the image doesn't show

```
holder.musicImage.load("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80")
```

but, if I load it from local or drawable, it loads with no problem

```
holder.musicImage.load(R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_box_24)
```

What is the problem? Can someone help? I'm using a coil for the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you get any error?

I suggest use Picasso because it is more powerfuller than this

anyway I use this code that work

```
val imageView:ImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view)

imageView!!.load("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Kotlin-logo.svg/1024px-Kotlin-logo.svg.png")
```

but something exist that you should pay attention to them

1-
in **app/build.gradle**

```
android {
   ...
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }

   kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
   }
}
```

2-
you must add **com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.11** library for coil work
because coil use okhttp for working

so do this

```
dependencies {

    ...

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.11'
}
```

I did them and it work well

Comment: i fix just wipe data my emulator and re run, maybe my project have corrupt or same name with other project, anyway thx for help